# Как запустить активити без нагрузки на ОС?

Tags: java, android, sql

Мне нужно открыть активити, и при этом отправить ей данные об элементе. Данные я получаю из адаптера в виде курсора, и помещаю их в интент. Вопрос, как мне открыть мгновенно активити, а потом только загрузить и отрендерить данные об

```
 cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), InfoActivity.class);
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) numberCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("number"));
            String slug = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("slug"));
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("number", number);
            intent.putExtra("slug", slug);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: getIntent запрашивайте в onResume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получайте данные в методе обратного вызова `onResume()` или `onStart()`, к моменту вызова этих методов активити будет полностью запущена и ее UI загружен и отображен на экране.